# 2008 R2 mouse movements are jumpy. PVSCSI issues also

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I am running ESX 4.0 Update 1 build 208167 and vCenter build 208111.

I am building a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise VM. The OS and VMware Tools get installed without any trouble. When I log into the VM, the mouse movements are very jumpy and not smooth. Jase McCarty pointed me to read KB Article: 1011709 , even though I am running Update 1, and tried removing the driver, but the problem still exists. just wondering if anyone else is seeing it.

I have built the machine with 2 different options. 1 using Bus Logis SAS and the other using PVSCSI. all with 1vCPU and 4GB of RAM and VMXNET3 NIC

When I build the machine with PVSCSI as boot, I mount the floppy .flp and the ISO for Win2k8r2. the install goes just fine when I specify the driver for PVSCSI, but once the install is done and has to reboot for the first time, the VM will hang on reboot with a blinking "_" on the screen, so I have to power off the VM and power it back on. If I remove the floppy .flp before the install reboots, then the machine will reboot and the installation will continue. Once the install has completed, I'm prompted to change the administrator passwor. If I leave the VM alone for a few minutes and come back to it, the VM will be frozen for about 20-30 seconds then I can move my mouse again. This is only experianced with 2008 R2 VM with a PVSCSI boot drive.

All of my other VMs seem to be working fine, but I wanted to start building out some new 2008 R2 VMs and test out PVSCSI as the boot drive.

if anyone else have tested these options, let me know if you are seeing any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morning once again TT (and all your friends that use your account) - are we looking at another busy day today?

Firstly PVSCSI isn't *supported* for boot drives, it might work but it's not supported - also using PVSCSI and/or VMXNET3 stops that VM from ever using Fault Tolerance - don't know if you knew that but it's worth knowing (it was a VCP4 question too by the way). Either way that could be your boot problem ok.

As for the mouse jumping about, are you talking about via the VSClient Console or RDP?

Comment: Hello. You helped us ;)

Comment: PVSCSI is supported for Windows boot drives starting with ESX 4.0 Update 1, released in November 2009 (VMWare KB Article: 1010398).

Answer (score 1):

As for the jumpy mouse on the vSphere console under 2008R2, you can get around this by editing the virtual machine settings and bumping up the video RAM to 16 or 32MB.